# Immutable.js not comparing by value

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm sure I'm somehow doing this incorrectly but I'm trying to use Immutable.js for functional programming and I'm having trouble comparing objects by value.
In the documentation, the Set data structure uses Immutable.is for equality and inclusion testing , and the page for Immutable.is states

`Value equality check with semantics similar to Object.is, but treats Immutable Collections as values, equal if the second Collection includes equivalent values`

However, when I test this behavior on Firefox's debugger, I get the following results:

```
let x = {a:1}
let y = {a:1}
is(x,y) //False
is({a:1},{a:1}) //False
Set.of({a:1}).includes({a:1}) //False
```

Then I thought maybe I have to use Immutable's map instead of the object literals, but I'm still getting the following:

```
let x = Map({a:1})
let y = Set(Map({a:1}))
y.includes(x) //False

let x = []
x.push(Map({a:1}))
x.includes(Map({a:1})) //False
```

I've also gotten similar results using .includes from Lodash, so I suppose there's something obvious that I'm just not seeing.
How do I compare items in a list by values?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you need to create a 2nd immutable object and then use .equals.

Comment: Immutable.js will not compare objects by property values. The is() method has the same semantics as Object.is() `both the same object (means both object have same reference)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before doing object equality comparisons, you need to turn your object into an [Immutable collection](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection).

You also need to do your equality comparison using the [Immutable.is()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/is) method.

```js
const x = {a:1}
const y = {a:1}
const xImmutable = Immutable.Map(x)
const yImmutable = Immutable.Map(y)
console.log(Immutable.is(x, y)) //false
console.log(x === y) //false
console.log(Immutable.is(xImmutable, yImmutable)) //true
console.log(xImmutable === yImmutable) //false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```